# Re-authorize the OAuth Application in GitHub CLI

Tags: github

I'm part of an organization, so I'm trying to clone a repo that is inside of that organization but every time that I've tried I get this error:

```
Cloning into 'diretory'...
remote: The `X' organization has enabled or enforced SAML SSO. To access
remote: this repository, you must re-authorize the OAuth Application `GitHub CLI`.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/X/Y.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Have you ever had a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it for me was to open the Credentials Manager of Windows and delete all GitHub-related entries. Then on my next interaction with GitHub, from Visual Studio in my case (should be similar for GitHub CLI), I got a prompt to sign in and after that, it all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned Github CLI tool can be accessed by the `gh` command.

For me, all I had to do was run `gh auth login` and follow the instructions.

Personally, I chose `HTTPs` and `Login with a web browser` when asked, pasted the one-time login code it gave me into my browser, entered my Github password, then after a few seconds it was all done and fixed.